# How to make such a border-radius for a block?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, border-radius

It is necessary that on full hd and with increasing content, the concave angle remains the same, that is, do not insert this background as a picture, but draw using css. The angle should look inside the block

This SVG from figma:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tD5N5.png)

I don't have any options left